# iPhone app has issues only if 3GS users upgrade in iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ios4, itunes-store

An upgrade to my app went live in iTunes. Only 3GS iPhones seem to be having an issue only if the 3GS did an upgrade of the app. If the 3GS iPhone does a fresh download or deletes the app and then downloads it, everything is fine.

I'm wondering if I have missed something from a coding perspective that should have prevented this issue?

I used several 3GS iPhone testers. Those same 3GS iPhones that tested the adhoc fine, have the upgrade issue. iPhone 4s have no issues whether downloads are new or upgrades.

Is there a chance that the upgrade is not truly replacing the previous version of there app?

Is there an Xcode setting to ensure such a thing?

Or is this some kind of fluke?

I have upgraded other apps in the past with similar functionality and had no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you had a breaking changes in your app data formats? If I remember correctly, iTunes upgrades backup the app data on the device and restores it back after the upgrade.

Comment: You have me thinking and I believe you are right! The app is probably reusing a stored setting that is no longer valid. Thanks!

Comment: On second thought the upgrade problem only exists on 3GS phones. If an iPhone 4 user upgrades they don't have an issue at all. Regardless, I will still investigate based on your answer.

Comment: It was quite subtle and complicated, but it turns out that in the end, it was based on a user default setting from the previous version as you described. Thanks a ton! I would not have looked in that direction without your suggestion.